# PDFBox: Clone font

Tags: fonts, clone, pdfbox

I am cloning a document for edit with following code.

```
cloneDoc = new PDDocument()
    PDFCloneUtility cloner = new PDFCloneUtility(cloneDoc);
for(int pageIndex = 0; pageIndex < mainDoc.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageIndex) {
    PDPage page = mainDoc.getPage(pageIndex);
    PDPage newPage = new PDPage((COSDictionary) cloner.cloneForNewDocument(page.getCOSObject()));
    newPage.setCropBox(page.getCropBox());
    newPage.setMediaBox(page.getMediaBox());
    newPage.setRotation(page.getRotation());
    if(null != page.getResources()) {
         newPage.setResources(new PDResources((COSDictionary) cloner.cloneForNewDocument(page.getResources())));
    } else {
         newPage.setResources(new PDResources());
    }
    cloneDoc.addPage(newPage);
}
```

Document gets cloned properly but font's are not getting cloned. Due to this text font & font size looks different and contains missing character.

The mainDoc has two fonts in mainDoc.getFontsToSubset() which are missing in cloneDoc.

Comment: I doubt the pdfbox classes have been designed for cloning of document data parts which are still in the process of being generated, and fonts to subset are such unfinished entities. One usually can clone data from `PDDocument` objects created by loading from file (or stream)  without substantial edits.

Comment: Indeed. That isn't what clone is for.

Comment: You could add the page directly to the destination, just avoid closing the source document before the destination document. There may be other drawbacks, you won't get the form fields properly.

Comment: The class was make public (by me!) in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3280 to solve a problem. Later it turned out that cloning wasn't the solution and this was reverted, but I couldn't remove the public because this would have broken the API. Reminds me to make it package local again for 3.0 :-)